# If I incorporate a UL/NRTL listed power supply in our product, must we re-test?

Tags: regulations, ul

We are building a product. It's a bench-top electrical testing thing, similar to a Keithley DMM or an oscilloscope in that it's something engineers would use at companies for testing stuff and occasionally would get built into other equipment.

I would like to incorporate the AC-DC power supply in the chassis so all the user plugs in is a power cable. In other words there would be no need for a wall-wart or desktop power supply.

The big concern is that we would need to get UL (or other NRTL) listed for some of our customers. But what if we purchased a UL listed power supply -- something like a PC's power supply with +12, +5, and -12 -- and incorporated it. It would bolt into our chassis and only the back side would be exposed to the customer. Could we claim UL listing?

Comment: This is a legal concern. I'd hesitate to have this here in EE Stack Exchange. After all, no answer here is a legally binding answer. The only reason I'm not voting to close it is because I myself am extremely curious.

Comment: Why in hell would you vote to close compliance questions? They are extremely confusing and difficult to understand, and completely inescapable to people who do this for a living.

Comment: I'd only vote to close if from EE, it should be moved to an open legally binding forum, like a lawyer. Any answer on here needs to make it clear that it's not the end all be all to the question, which means this is really an "opinion" based answer. **IF**, however, a lawyer were to comment on this (I'll be waiting until the heat death of the universe for a lawyer to hand out free legal advice), that would be the only "non-opinion" based answer.

Comment: @Dave hate to disappoint, but you should regard *all* the answers you find on internet message boards as 'opinion'

Comment: @Daniel, what's more of a disappointment is that that you'd say that. A well written, well documented, and corroborated answer is as much fact on the internet as it is in text books, or anywhere else. However, I still stand that the only source that could answer this question without opinion is a Lawyer.

Comment: @Dave Unfortunately the only person who is qualified to answer it authoritatively is the person who signs the listing certificate at the test lab. No one else knows what that guy wants, and his opinion is the only one that matters. You can have consensus on the likely answer, but capital-T Truth is hard to come by.

Comment: A sales rep at Athena Power (http://athenapower.com/) says that if we used a UL listed supply we could claim UL listing.

Comment: A rep at Dell says that they have their PCs tested as complete units.

Comment: A rep at UL says that we could claim "Power supply UL listed" but we could not claim the system as a whole is listed.

Comment: That actually sounds plausible. ...and considering the source fairly authoritative! Thanks for researching on this and reporting the results!

Comment: They're supposedly getting back to me on the question about how "Power supply UL listed" versus "UL Listed" might affect customers.

Answer (score 1):

THIS IS ONLY AN OPINION AND IS NOT AUTHORITATIVE IN ANY WAY. THIS DOES NOT CONSTITUTE "ADVICE"

In my past experience, simply using a listed power supply does not grant you immunity from the listing/compliance process.

It is possible that using a fully-enclosed, finger-protected supply like an ATX-style will make your testing extremely easy -- using a wall-wart style would make it even easier -- but I would very much suspect that you can't "claim UL listing" just by using one.

Unlike CE mark, UL, RTL, etc are not self-certifications.

Comment: This sounds feasible to me, since using even the best supply doesn't mean you have definitely connected the earth ground to the chassis.

Comment: I wonder how it works with PCs. All these PC manufacturers buy UL listed supplies and throw them into various different models. Are they testing *every* different model at a NRTL?

Comment: Possibly! Or the case may not be UL listed at all, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Having spent 3 years working at UL, I can say with almost near certainty the answer to this is no. You will still have to test the rest of your product. 
I will say, if you want to get a UL listing then you should definitely use a UL listed supply. It would be considered a "critical component" which means UL would want to see that it has already undergone its own safety evaluation. If you bought a knock-off non-Listed power supply, you'd first have to evaluate the power supply on its own, then your end-product.

Hope this helps.